# if $x=e^s$, $y=e^t$, then $x^2\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+y^2\frac{d^2u}{dy^2}+x\frac{du}{dx}+y\frac{du}{dy}=0$ implies $\frac{d^2u}{ds^2}+\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

if $x=e^s$, $y=e^t$, then $x^2\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+y^2\frac{d^2u}{dy^2}+x(\begin{matrix}
du \\
dx
\end{matrix})$ $+y(\begin{matrix}
du \\
dy
\end{matrix}) =0$
implies $\frac{d^2u}{ds^2}+\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}=0$. I'm not entirely sure, about the problem if might be $x^2\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+y^2\frac{d^2u}{dy^2}+x\frac{du}{dx}+y\frac{du}{dy}$ I tried doing $s=ln(x)$ and $t=ln(y)$ so that I have $\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{d^2u}{ds^2}$ and $\frac{d^2u}{dy^2}=\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}. $ However I'm not sure about the third and fourth term.

Comment: What is $u$? What are $s$ and $t$? Could you please write the functions explicitly, i.e. $u(x,y)$ rather than $u$ to clarify

Comment: It is from a book, it does not say anything about u,s, and t. I assume s and t is some independent function, while u is a function of $x,y$. That is actually all the information the problem provides, which is why I am not sure. However assuming $s,t$ independent, $x(s), y(t), u(x,y)$; do you have any suggestion?

Comment: The question title is an inaccurate summary of the question.

Comment: My bad, I fixed it

Comment: Is this the notation your book uses? At least the derivatives of $u$ should be partial derivatives I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the chain rule, $$\frac{du}{ds}=u_xx_s+u_yy_s,$$ so we can apply the chain rule again to find$$\frac{d^2u}{ds^2}=u_{xx}x_s^2+u_xx_{ss}+u_{yy}y_s^2+u_yy_{ss}+2u_{xy}y_sx_s.$$ Analogously, $$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}=u_{xx}x_t^2+u_xx_{tt}+u_{yy}y_t^2+u_yy_{tt}+2u_{xy}y_tx_t.$$ We have $x_s=x$ and $y_t=t$, and $x_t=y_s=0$. Thus, we write $$\frac{d^2u}{ds^2}=u_{xx}x^2+u_xx$$ and $$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}=u_{yy}y^2+u_yy.$$ Thus,  $$\frac{d^2u}{ds^2}+\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}=u_{yy}y^2+u_yy+u_{xx}x^2+u_xx=0$$

Comment: Could you check my answer?

Comment: See my comment. I believe it works out after you fix that.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x^2\dfrac{\mathrm d^2u}{\mathrm dx^2} + y^2\dfrac{\mathrm d^2u}{\mathrm dy^2} + x\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx} + y\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dy} &=& 0 \\
x^2\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx} + y^2\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dy} + x\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx} + y\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dy} &=& 0 \\
e^{2s}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm de^s}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm de^s} + e^{2t}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm de^t}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm de^t} + e^s\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm de^s} + e^t\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm de^t} &=& 0 \\
e^{2s}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm de^s}e^{-s}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm ds} + e^{2t}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm de^t}e^{-t}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt} + \dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm ds} + \dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt} &=& 0 \\
e^{2s}\left(-e^{-2s}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm ds} + e^{-s}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm de^s}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm ds}\right) + e^{2t}\left(-e^{-2t}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt} + e^{-t}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm de^t}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}\right) + \dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm ds} + \dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt} &=& 0 \\
e^{2s}\left(-e^{-2s}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm ds} + e^{-2s}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm ds}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm ds}\right) + e^{2t}\left(-e^{-2t}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt} + e^{-2t}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}\right) + \dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm ds} + \dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt} &=& 0 \\
-\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm ds} + \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm ds}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm ds} -\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt} + \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt} + \dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm ds} + \dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt} &=& 0 \\
\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm ds}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm ds} + \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt} &=& 0 \\
\dfrac{\mathrm d^2u}{\mathrm ds^2} + \dfrac{\mathrm d^2u}{\mathrm dt^2} &=& 0 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: There is a mistake with product/chain rule in going from line 4 to 5. $$\frac{d}{de^s}\left(e^{-s}\frac{du}{ds})\right)=\frac{du}{ds}\frac{d}{de^s}e^{-s}+e^{-s}\frac{d}{de^s}\frac{du}{ds}=-e^{-2s}\frac{du}{ds}+e^{-2s}\frac{d^2u}{ds^2}$$